# Customizing web directory page

Tags: html, apache

I recently went to a webpage and noticed their directory page was customized.

```
putlocker.is/featured/
```

NOT

```
putlocker.is/featured
```

How would I costumize this on an Apache sever?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean it's customized? I don't see anything special about the webpage you linked to. Do you mean it doesn't directly link to a file name?

Comment: It's a folder in the root called "featured"... Just add a folder.

Comment: @KodleeYin But the folder is customized.

Comment: @Adam That is the non-custumized directory. Go to said webpage to see customized directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you provide almost certainly isn't an Apache directory index (although there are some directives which can customise those, such as [`IndexStyleSheet`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexstylesheet)). To achieve a custom page when a URL with a `/` on the end is requested then, given a vanilla Apache configuration:

Put an HTML document in that directory with a filename that is in the list specified by [the `DirectoryIndex` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex). Usually this will include `index.html`.

You can also use a file that will generate HTML programmatically (such as PHP on a system with PHP installed) or divert the request (e.g. using [`ScriptAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias) or [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)) to another program (which might use the [front controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern)).

Here is an example to use [Catalyst for this purpose](http://wiki.catalystframework.org/wiki/deployment/apache_fastcgi.view), you then define your URLs using [Catalyst actions](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Catalyst-Manual-5.9007/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Intro.pod#Action_types).

Comment: @Krii — See the parenthesized section of the first sentence, and all the other directives on the page I linked to from it.

Comment: index.html works. Thanks.